# Can't find ClientAssertionCertificate in ASP.NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, active-directory, asp.net-core-1.0, adal

I have an ASP.NET Core application and I am trying to get the access token from AAD using a certificate. I am using `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` assembly of version 3.13.5.907. But it seems that the `ClientAssertionCertificate` class has been removed from this assembly. The interface `IClientAssertionCertificate` is available but I can't find any class that is imlpementing it.

In ASP.NET 4.5 I used to use the following code for getting access token from AAD using certificates (`Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` assembly of version 3.13.4.878)

```
var clientCredential = new ClientAssertionCertificate(_appId, _thumbprint);
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredential);
```

Has this class been depreciated in ASP.NET Core or am I missing something?

Comment: Not implemented: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/701

Comment: Coming soon: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/598

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue today; turns out it is pretty easy to write your own concrete implementation of IClientAssertionCertificate

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;

namespace app{

    internal class ClientAssertionCertificate : IClientAssertionCertificate {

        private X509Certificate2 certificate;
        public string ClientId { get; private set; }

        public string Thumbprint {
            get {
                return Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(certificate.GetCertHash());
            }
        }

        public ClientAssertionCertificate(string clientId, X509Certificate2 certificate) {
            ClientId = clientId;
            this.certificate = certificate;
        }

        public byte[] Sign(string message) {
            using (var key = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey()) {
                return key.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In addition to referencing package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, you'll also need to add the package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens (for the Base64UrlEncoder)

Source: https://blog.mastykarz.nl/azure-ad-app-only-access-token-using-certificate-dotnet-core/

Comment: Thanks for this.  This implementation also works under Mono, working around an issue with AAD / KeyVault https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/509

Answer (score 3):

Just an update to anyone seeing this post now. This is now available in the latest .NETStandard 2.0 version.